# Could intelligent life arise on a planet that isn't 'tethered' to a star, just drifting near to one?

Tags: xenobiology, astronomy, solar-system, origin-of-life

Earth's movement in space is obviously linked to the Sun, as are many other planets. But what I'm asking, is could intelligent life develop on a world that is merely 'passing by' and basking in a nearby star's light, swinging through a habitable zone and profiting briefly? This would make sure that liquid water exists and energy reaches the planet, but could this be realistic?

Comment: A planet such as this is termed a "[Rogue Planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_planet)". One issue I see with your premise is that a rogue planet that was swinging by a star close enough to enter the habitable zone, but not being permanently captured, is not likely to spend more than a single year in that zone. Even swinging by an O class star, it won't spend more than 1000 years in the habitable zone, which is not long enough for life to evolve.

Comment: See the Arthur C. Clarke short story "Crusade". It has a rogue planet with liquid helium(?) oceans that supercool massive superconducting AIs. Yes, intelligence is possible. Just maybe not "conventional" carbon-based lifeforms.

Comment: Tempted to vote to close as duplicate ([from review](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/review/close/63484)) however, to me it seems more, "unclear what you are asking". Not voting at present, watching.

Comment: @Lelu: Or Larry Niven's Outsiders, another life form based on liquid helium.  (IIRC: they're pretty cool, anyway :-))  But having their planet make a close approach to a star would kill them off - about like having Earth spend a year inside the orbit of Mercury.

Comment: 'is it possible' style questions are generally poor questions.  The answer is yes unless its clearly physically impossible, which it isn't in this case.

Comment: Question suggested as a duplicate talks about "supporting" life, not its evolution. Also the accepted answer isn't helpful at all.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically it is possible...all living species including the human race have shown results of evolving and adapting at speed so I believe that it is possible for a living organism to be born on a planet without a sun but I also believe that this organism could have instant adaptation capability...so when this planet passes a sun/star the light could trigger a rapid evolution...one day we might find out...or not...keep your eyes to the stars...